# My app crashes when i launch i think the error is in the firebase code how can i solve it?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a problem here, i created my app that takes data from firebase, i created this app but when i launch it it crashes, I tried to delete all the code in my MainActivity.java and test all the code trying to detect the problem and i found out that any line with this name "firebase" causes crash, check my `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView mItemList;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Global");
    mDatabase.keepSynced(true);

    mItemList= findViewById(R.id.rv);
    mItemList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mItemList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts,PostsViewHolder>firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostsViewHolder>
            (Posts.class,R.layout.row_item,PostsViewHolder.class,mDatabase) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(PostsViewHolder viewHolder, Posts model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
            viewHolder.setNickName(model.getNick_name());
        }
    };

    mItemList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
public static class PostsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    View mView;
    public PostsViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        mView=itemView;
    }
    public  void setTitle(String title)
    {
        TextView postTitle =(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.id_title);
        postTitle.setText(title);
    }
    public  void setDesc(String desc)
    {
        TextView postDesc =(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.id_description);
        postDesc.setText(desc);
    }
    public  void setNickName(String nick_name)
    {
        TextView postNickName =(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.id_username);
        postNickName.setText(nick_name);
    }
}
```

}

any line with the name "Firebase" causes crash, i mean if i delete these two lines from `onCreate()`

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Global");
    mDatabase.keepSynced(true);
```

and the `onStart()` method

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts,PostsViewHolder>firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostsViewHolder>
            (Posts.class,R.layout.row_item,PostsViewHolder.class,mDatabase) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(PostsViewHolder viewHolder, Posts model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
            viewHolder.setNickName(model.getNick_name());
        }
    };

    mItemList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

the app opens without crashing but it doesnt read data from Firebase now, so i think the problem is in the `onStart()` method and in these two lines from `onCreate` 
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Logcat, please.

Comment: Add null check for each method return type before using it... FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Global"); mDatabase.keepSynced(true);

Comment: Please add you entire error.